# Remove only parentheses in nested parentheses

Tags: python, regex, parentheses, parse-tree

I have a bank of parse tree with invalid format where the words wrapped in parentheses.

```
string = (NP  (NN  (Police)) (SBAR  (SC (for)) (S  (NP-SBJ  (*)) (VP  (VB (secure)) (NP  (NN      (olympic games)))))))
```

I have tried to remove the parentheses without the word inside it turns out I remove all of them.

```
re.sub(r'[\(\)]','',string)
```

and this doesn't work too.

```
re.sub(r'\s\(.*\)\))
```

Because I think the pattern based on the second closed parentheses like

```
(Police)) (for)) (*)) (secure)) (olympic games))
```

I want to remove the parentheses which flanked the word without the word removed like this. Any help?

```
result = (NP  (NN Police) (SBAR  (SC for) (S  (NP-SBJ  *) (VP  (VB secure) (NP  (NN  olympic games))))))
```

Comment: Try `re.sub(r'\(([^()\s]*)\)', r'\1', s)`, see https://ideone.com/pD0I9j

Comment: It works!! Thanks!! @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
re.sub(r'\(([^()]*)\)', r'\1', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/B0VT04/2).

**Details**

- `\(` - a `(` char
- `([^()]*)` - Group 1 (`\1` refers to this group value from the replacement pattern): 0 or more chars other than parentheses
- `\)` -

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/lY1eKq):

```
import re
s = "(NP  (NN  (Police)) (SBAR  (SC (for)) (S  (NP-SBJ  (*)) (VP  (VB (secure)) (NP  (NN      (olympic games)))))))"
print(re.sub(r'\(([^()]*)\)', r'\1', s))
# => (NP  (NN  Police) (SBAR  (SC for) (S  (NP-SBJ  *) (VP  (VB secure) (NP  (NN      olympic games))))))
```

Comment: It should be re.sub(r'\(([^()]*)\)', r'\1', s) to give the desired answer.

Comment: @Dave [OP confirms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55262830/remove-only-parentheses-in-nested-parentheses/55263700?noredirect=1#comment97258621_55262830) that `re.sub(r'\(([^()\s]*)\)', r'\1', s)` works as expected. If `\s` is removed, `(abc def)` like substrings will also get deleted

Comment: The output of your answer doesn't match the OP's desired output; see 'olympic games'

Comment: @Dave Well, I don't understand OP then :) Edited the answer.